# How to disable archiving for deleted content in Alfresco 3.4d

Tags: alfresco

How to disable archiving of deleted content in Alfresco?
I am using Alfresco 3.4d.

Tried by setting `system.content.eagerOrphanCleanup` to `true` in repository.properties...

I want to delete content from alfresco in one shot, I don't want to move this deleted content to `contentstore.deleted`

Thanks,
Yogesh